# Create, read, and update from SQL table to on-prem SharePoint 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, sql, external-list, external-data, custom-bdc

Ultimately I would like to create an external list that can be customized (i.e., partly columns from a SQL table and partly native SharePoint columns).

BCS isn't an option because it would not let me create extra columns in a SharePoint "external" list. I am a beginner programmer, but I am looking into creating a BDC model or some kind of SharePoint add-in on VS to populate SQL data into a custom SP list.

Is there code that exists for this? Or some method that already exists that can lead me through? I'm at a loss after numerous attempts and would appreciate the help.